# How to set focus on textarea which is rendered inside v-for in Vuejs 2?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

In my Vue.js component, I rendered table rows containing `textarea` based on a list of items as following:

```html
<template>
    <div>
       <table>
           <tr v-for="(item, index) in items">
               <td>{{ index }}</td>
               <td><textarea v-model="item.message"></textarea></td>
           </tr>
       </table>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data: {
            items: [
               { message: 'Foo' },
               { message: 'Bar' }
            ]
        }
    };
</script>
```

When I click anywhere in a row, I want the `textarea` inside that row to be focused. How can I do that?

The following code cannot solve the problem:

```
 this.$refs.myTextArea.focus();
```

This only works with element with unique ref `id` and outside of `v-for`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to specify an unique ref name to each text area like :

```
    <tr v-for="(item, index) in items" @click="focus('ta'+index)">
               <td>{{ index }}</td>
               <td><textarea v-model="item.message" :ref="'ta'+index"></textarea></td>
           </tr>
```

`focus` method :

```
methods:{
  focus(key){
    this.$refs[key][0].focus()
   }
}
```

check this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/bos95hgj/)

Comment: I have tried that, but since `textarea` with `ref` attribute is rendered inside `v-for`, calling `focus()` does not have any effect. Note that if I say: `this.$refs[textAreaIndex].style.cssText = "background-color:red;` to apply style on the element, it works as well, but calling `focus()` does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding a dynamic value for ref on each row?

Then you can react to click events and select the proper textarea based on that attribute.

Something like:

```
<template>
    <div>
       <table>
           <tr v-for="(item, index) in items" v-on:click="focusTextArea(index)">
               <td>{{ index }}</td>
               <td>
                 <textarea ref="textArea{{index}}" v-model="item.message"></textarea>
               </td>
           </tr>
       </table>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data: {
            items: [
               { message: 'Foo' },
               { message: 'Bar' }
            ]
        },
        methods: {
          focusTextArea: (textAreaIndex) => {
            this.$refs[`textArea{textAreaIndex}`].$el.focus();
          }
        }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: I have tried that, but since `textarea` with `ref` attribute is rendered inside `v-for`, calling `focus()` does not have any effect. Note that if I say: `this.$refs[textAreaIndex].style.cssText = "background-color:red;`, to apply style on the element, it works as well, but calling `focus()`  does not work.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add the .$el to get the actual HTMLElement. I updated my code. My proposition should work now :)

Comment: You cannot call `$el` because element is rendered inside `v-for`, what you get from `this.$refs[myKey]` is an array e.g. `[<textarea></textarea>]`. You call `this.$refs[key][0].focus()`. Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: I do not understand why you say I can't call .$el but anyway, great that you solved your issue :) Cheers!

Comment: When I do `this.$refs[textAreaIndex].$el.focus();`, I get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$el' of undefined`. I think this is because there is no `ref` attribute being used in our sample template above.

Comment: I was in a hurry and forgot to add the ref to the textarea element. Damn, that was stupid from my side. Sorry! Now my answer is correct